# Hot to build Firebase Chat Room database?

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to struct firestore database for chat application. 
I want to add owner's reference of chat room into specific chat room. here is my simple database screenshot.

[image]

But A lot of database structure examples of chat app use just "id" of String for owner field. not reference. I think this is like RDBMS. What's the right way?

(p.s) Here is my code to get owner's name. Is it right way?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, using a string or a Reference will not make a big difference from a developer perspective.

According to this official Firebase video, **at the time of writing**, the Reference data type mainly "provides value in the Firebase console UI". You may watch the video starting at 4:37 for more detailed information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elg2zDVIcLo&t=277

With both of these data types (Text string and Reference) you can "point" to a document and read the corresponding data, mimicking a primary key-foreign key relationship in SQL.

For example, as explained in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore?authuser=0#doc) you can create a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) from a slash-separated path, like `firebase.firestore().doc('/User/user_1')` using the **string** value of the field `owner`.

Comment: Thanks! so if i use a string "uid" and wanna get onwer's name, do have to send api to get owner's id and then send api again with "owner's uid" to get owner's name?

Comment: I guess that when you say `uid` you refer to the `user_1` value in the owner field, right?

Comment: I mean onwer's document id as "String value"

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Could you describe it in detail with the elements/values that are in your image and not by using values or elements that are not, like uid, because it is not clear.

Comment: Sorry You are right. I mean user_1 !

Comment: As explained in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore?authuser=0#doc) you can create a `DocumentReference` form the entire slash-separated path, like `db.doc('/User/user_1')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190156/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-shutupiloveyou).

Comment: I can't talk in chat yet....

Comment: I have edited post.